# LWJGL texture bleeding fix won't work

Tags: opengl, java, textures, lwjgl

I tried a lot of things to fix texture bleeding, but nothing works. I don't want to add a transparent border around my textures, because I already got too many and it would take too much time and I can't do it with code because I'm loading textures with slick. My textures are seperate textures and they seem to wrap on the other side (texture bleeding).

Here are the textures that are "bleeding":

[image: The bleeding texture]

The head, body, arm and leg are seperate textures.

Here's the code I'm using to draw a texture:

```
public static void drawTextureN(Texture texture, Vector2f position, Vector2f translation, Vector2f origin,Vector2f scale,float rotation, Color color, FlipState flipState)
    {
        texture.setTextureFilter(GL11.GL_NEAREST);


        color.bind();
        texture.bind();


        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);

        GL11.glTranslatef((int)position.x, (int)position.y, 0);
        GL11.glTranslatef(-(int)translation.x, -(int)translation.y, 0);
        GL11.glRotated(rotation, 0f, 0f, 1f);

        GL11.glScalef(scale.x, scale.y, 1);

        GL11.glTranslatef(-(int)origin.x, -(int)origin.y, 0);

        float pixelCorrection = 0f;

        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(0,0);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(texture.getTextureWidth(),0);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(texture.getTextureWidth(),texture.getTextureHeight());
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(0,texture.getTextureHeight());

        GL11.glEnd();

        GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    }
```

I tried a half pixel correction but it didn't make any sense because GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE. I set pixelCorrection to 0, but it still wont work.

Answer (score 1):

Texture must be a square with measurements of an exponent of two (16, 32, 64, 128, etc...), so re-size the file to one of those.  I tend to use 1024 X 1024 for item textures.  Otherwise LWJGL gets all messed up and the texture 'bleeds.'

Answer (score 0):

Since you are drawing a single texture onto a single quad at a time, shouldn't the texture coordinates of all the vertices be either 0 or 1 (all 4 permutations of that for each of the 4 corners)? Texture coordinates range from 0 and 1, 0 being the start and 1 being the end of the texture in s and t.

Namely:

```
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    GL11.glVertex2f(0,0);

    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,0);
    GL11.glVertex2f(texture.getTextureWidth(),0);

   // etc...
```

Comment: They >do< range from 0 to 1.

Comment: I mean, why are they not literally 0 and 1?

Comment: That was a half pixel correction try, which didn't make much sense because GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE.

Comment: Are your texture dimensions powers of two by any chance?

Comment: No, there not, is this a problem?

Comment: Yes, special code is required if they are not. Try scaling them so that the dimensions are powers of two and hard code 0 and 1 for the texture coordinates. Let me know how it works out.

Comment: I'll try tomorrow.

Comment: Okay I just saw, that my textures are indeed powers of two, because I'm loading the textures with slick.

Comment: And all of your texture coordinates are exactly (0,0), (1,0), (1,1), and (0,1)? Because clamp_edge will not just stop the texture: http://www.felixgers.de/teaching/jogl/textureClamp.html

Comment: Ok changed the code to hard coded values. But no visual changes.

Comment: Is your character in the correct location on the screen? i.e. Is he supposed to be floating? If not you may be applying your transformations to the wrong matrix (modelview is the one you want).

Comment: Yes, it's the correct position.